Pinned Scroll Headers arn't working SwiftUI
I have a basic scrollview that has pinned headers (dates) that are pinned at the top as the scrollview is scrolled. The pinned headers work for the most part but many times they stop pinning and are scrolled as normal parts of the scroll view. I'm not sure if this is related but sometimes I experienced this after pulling to refresh the scroll view with .refreshable. Or sometimes even leaving the app for a while and coming back. Am I doing something wrong? I tried to create as simple of code as I can so you can see my setup.
video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZUoMF60jkXl5RigOAFp0SdnpJVIohRwj/view?usp=sharing
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct HomeFeedView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var canRefresh = true
    @Namespace var hero
   
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 10, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]){
                Color.clear.frame(height: 1).id("scrolltop")
                
                let data = getData()
                
                ForEach(data) { holder in
                    Section {
                        ForEach(holder) { release in
                            NavigationLink {
                                ReleaseView()
                                    .navigationTransition(.zoom(sourceID: "\(holder.id)\(release.id ?? "")", in: hero))
                            } label: {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).frame(height: 150)
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                            .matchedTransitionSource(id: "\(holder.id)\(release.id ?? "")", in: hero)
                        }
                    } header: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("December 31st").font(.headline).bold()
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 12).padding(.vertical, 12)
                        .background(.ultraThickMaterial)
                    }
                }
            
                
                Color.clear.frame(height: 120)
            }
        }
        .safeAreaPadding(.top, 60 + top_Inset())
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .refreshable {
            if canRefresh {
                canRefresh = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
                    canRefresh = true
                }
                
                // Some backend operation
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
            headerView()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    func getData() -> [String] {

        return []
    }
    @ViewBuilder
    func headerView() -> some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(colorScheme == .dark ? "wealthLogoWhite" : "wealthLogo")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(height: 55)
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 100).padding(.horizontal).padding(.bottom, 10)
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
    }
}

